# Laravel Seeding Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, seeding

I'm using Laravel and I'm trying to seed some data into my database(phpmyadmin). I have two tables, users and carrinho. Their relationship is Users hasMany Carrinho. In the Carrinho table, I have a foreign key IDUser. I'm getting errors when I try to seed Carrinho.
Here is my CarrinhoSeeder file:

```
<?php

class CarrinhoTableSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run()
{
    DB::table('carrinho')->delete();

    $carrinho = array(
        array(
            'IDUser' => 1,
            'estado'      => true,
        ),
        array(
            'IDUser' => 2,
            'estado'      => true,
        )
    );

    DB::table('carrinho')->insert( $carrinho );
}

}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`loj
>     a`.`carrinho`, CONSTRAINT `carrinho_iduser_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`IDUser`) REFERENCES `users` (`IDUser`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
>     (SQL: insert into `carrinho` (`IDUser`, `estado`) values (1, 1), (2, 1))

Does anybody know what I have wrong?

Comment: The rows you are referencing, do they exist?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the users with the referenced IDs (1 & 2) already exist in the database. If it still doesn't work, you can temporarily disable foreign key checks with the following:

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');

DB::table('carrinho')->insert( $carrinho );

DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @sisou 's answer is enough to solve the problem, but I thing that is not quite the way that should be followed.

Disabling **foreign key checks is not a good idea**. This will hamper data integrity & may cause problems in future,

Just make sure that you've users with those ID's (that you're referencing in `carrinho` table).

Your error clearly pointing that **you don't have those users in users table**.

Hope by adding users with those ID's will solve your problem.

**Btw**, you column naming is also not in compliance with Laravel convention. Laravel will be expection `user_id` by default but u'r using `IDUser`. This will cause problem. 
So you've to poing that in your relationship.
If you have blur lines in Laravel relationships then you can check the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)